# Absolute-position elements on top of scrollable area and scroll two different elements at once

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, position

Basically what I want to do is have two strips, one of the left and one on top of a grid (both listboxes that will contain text elements). When the user scrolls inside my grid I want these two listson the sides to remain visible.

For example these strips could be rulers (and just have numbers and lines on them) and when the users scroll to the right, the 'ruler' on top scolls along witht the grid but the ruler on the left side remains visible. Same thing when the user scrolls vertically: the numbers on the ruler on the side increase but the ruler on top is still visible.

Here's an image (with only one ruler though, that show what I want to do. The blue square is basically the window and if it's scrolled horizontally the sidebar is still visible, but if it's scrolled vertically, the sidebar color changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define two grids in your xaml.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
     <Grid x:Name="Grid1">
       //scrollviewer code
     </Grid>
     <Grid x:Name="Grid2">
       //sidebar code
     </Grid>
 </Grid>
```

Grid 1 contains scrollview and Grid 2 contains sidebar. The two grids should be defined within the same parent. It will make them overlap each other. On Manipulation events you can play with their visibility. I hope this helps.

Comment: Which manipulation methods are there that can help me with this? Is there some method I can call every time the user scrolls Grid 1 so I can adjust the position of the sidebars at that point? Or something else that can help me? I know how I have to nest these elements in the xaml file but it's the scrolling that I'm stuck with.

Comment: There's no started event listed on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.95).aspx